# How to disambiguate multiple inherited typedefs from templated bases?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, typedef, multiple-inheritance

**Edit: I'm using tdm-gcc-4.7.1-2 for Windows**

Not sure how to resolve this.  I'd like to use this as a sort of type list that will let me know I'm attempting to use a type not present in `B`'s typedefs.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct A {
    typedef pair<T, U> type;
};

struct B : A<int, string>, A<int, float> {};

B::type foo; // won't compile, ambiguous reference, as expected
B::A<int, int>::type bar; // compiles fine?? :(
```

Is there a way to get it to fail on `A<int, int>` (and any other `A`'s not inherited by `B`), or another way to go about this?  I guess I could use a `tuple` and recurse my way through it, doing an `is_same` comparison on each element vs whatever I feed the metafunction, but this seemed easier... at first :\

Comment: I doubt that `B::A<int,int>::type` should compile at all... `B::A` is already ambiguous and does not refer to the template but to one of the instantiations from which `B` derives...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree, I don't see why it compiles.  I'm probably missing a rule buried in the standard.

Comment: I believe the section is 14.6.1-4 in c++11 draft. Explicitly allows this case

Comment: Did you try making the typedef `protected`? Or adding a `protected: typedef pair<T,U> protected_type;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because class templates have their template-name injected; the injected name can be used either as a template or a type referring to the template instantiation (14.6.1p1).  The injected class name is then inherited by the derived class (10.2p5); using it as a template is unambiguous (it's the same template however it is inherited) so is allowed.

To fix your program, try using `is_base_of`:

```
struct B : A<int, string>, A<int, float> { };
template<typename T, typename U>
using check_A = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A<T, U>, B>::value, A<T, U>>::type;

check_A<int, float>::type bar1; // compiles
check_A<int, int>::type bar2; // error
```

Comment: Nice call on the base check! :D  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In §11.1/5, the Standard says:

> In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will find the
>   injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in the scope
>   in which it was declared. The injected-class-name might be less
>   accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which it
>   was declared.

So `A` is an injected name in the scope of `B`. It refers to the template `A`, not the base class (because it would be ambiguous) according to §14.1/4.

Just like in the scope of `A`, if you say just `A`, it's the class itself (but it's the template in this context). You're making use of this injected name, and so the name `B::A` is the same as `::A`. I don't think there's a way to suppress this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The standard explicitly allows this, though it's a bit confusing. From 14.6.1-4 in draft:

> A lookup that finds an injected-class-name (10.2) can result in an
>   ambiguity in certain cases (for example, if it is found in more than
>   one base class). If all of the injected-class-names that are found
>   refer to specializations of the same class template, and if the name
>   is followed by a template-argument-list, the reference refers to the
>   class template itself and not a specialization thereof, and is not
>   ambiguous.

```
[ Example: 
template <class T> struct Base { }; 
template <class T> struct Derived: Base<int>, Base<char> { 
typename Derived::Base b; // error: ambiguous 
typename Derived::Base<double> d;// OK 
}; 
— end example ]
```